# Where does Django controller logic live?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having trouble working out where to put controller logic in my Django project.

I have models for players (think like chess players) who will be rated by ELO scores. After a round, two players have their ELO scores modified and updated. The next matches are chosen based on the players who have so far participated in the least number of contests.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    tournament_class = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # each player is part of a single tournament class
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contests = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_contest = models.IntegerField(default=0) # round number of last contest participated in
    ELO = models.FloatField(default=1000) # current ELO ranking
```

Where would I put control logic like the following functions?

```
def select_candidates()
    # return candidates who have participated in the least number of contests

def update_ELO_scores (winner,loser)
    # updates ELO scores based on match results
```

From what I have read, I think these functions I want to write should not live in the models, as these functions do not relate to single object instances. They might belong in a custom manager, as they do work on QuerySets, or do they belong in a QuerySet manager or a seperate package (python file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't use the concept of a controller per se, but this should be helpful: In a relational database environment, Django models take care of the row-based operations, while Managers take care of the table-based operation for those rows.

If your functions represent many instances of a model, they should be part of that model's manager. You can read more about declaring custom managers [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/)

Django allows you to structure your models in many ways, you can put all your managers in a different module if you want, but many projects make the `models` module into a folder, add a submodule for every model, and share the file with the manager.

```
|- views.py
|- apps.py
`- models
   `-|- __init__.py
     `- player.py #this contains the Model class and the Manager class.
```